# Troubles understanding finding elements in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, find, element

I'm trying to follow use find elements from http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name; however, they seem to work only half the time and usually on more simple sites. I'm wondering why that is. For example, currently i am trying to locate :

```
<a class="username" title="bruceleenation" href="/profile/u/3618527996"></a>
```

using :

```
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('username')
```

but i'm getting nothing. The html is from

https://gyazo.com/b2a0d389da26bbd325baaa5f915d0569
or

```
<body>

    <nav id="nav-sidebar" class="nav-main"></nav>
    <main id="page-content" class="" style="margin-right: 17px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
     <header class="header-logged"></header>
    <section class="page-content-wrapper"></section>
    <section class="media-slider" style="display: block;">
        <div class="close-slider"></div>
        <section id="slider" class="open" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a class="go-back" data-media-id="1322612612609855850_3618527996" title="Back to all media" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
            <section class="media-viewer-wrapper viewer" data-count-comments="0" data-count-likes="1" data-url-delete="/aj/d" data-url-comment="/aj/c" data-url-unlike="/aj/ul" data-url-like="/aj/l" data-user-id="3618527996" data-media-id="1322612612609855850_3618527996">
                <section class="mobile-user-info"></section>
                <section class="desktop-wrapper">
                    <section class="user-image-wrapper">
                        <div class="image-like-click"></div>
                        <a class="user-image-shadow" href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <img class="user-image" alt="" src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.0…493235_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMyMjYxMjYxMjYwOTg1NTg1MA%3D%3D.2"></img>
                        </a>
                        <section class="image-actions-wrapper dropdown-anchor"></section>
                    </section>
                    <section class="media-viewer-info ui-front">
                        <section class="user-info-wrapper text-translate-parent-wrapper ">
                            <a class="user-avatar-wrapper profile" title="bruceleenation" href="/profile/u/3618527996"></a>
                            <section class="user-info">
                                <a class="username" title="bruceleenation" href="/profile/u/3618527996">

                                    bruceleenation

                                </a>
                                <p class="full-name"></p>
                                <div class="media-date-geo">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </section>
```

Any suggestions on what to do? I've tried Xpath as well. `["//a[@class='username'"]`

Comment: Are you sure the element is present at the time you're looking for it?  It's fairly common for pages to alter their content on the fly.

Comment: Also, have you tried performing a time.sleep(N)?  Often times if pages are complex they could take a moment to load and so some components aren't on the page immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until element present as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.username[title = 'bruceleenation']")))
```